# Appium Grid- Exception coming as: ’Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.’ in one of the devices

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I am using Appium grid for parallel testing. I am running test cases on two devices connected as nodes to a single machine in which the Hub is running locally.
Test runs well in any one of the devices. However, on the other device, the App just gets installed and launched but there is no further UI action.
The error for this device is:

> Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Here is the JSON configs for the two devices:

JSON config 1:

```
{
   “configuration”:{
      “proxy”:“org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy”,
      “cleanUpCycle”:2000,
      “port”:59793,
      “host”:“127.0.0.1”,
      “maxSession”:1,
      “hubHost”:“127.0.0.1”,
      “registerCycle”:5000,
      “hubPort”:4444,
      “timeout”:10800,
      “url”:“127.0.0.1:59793/wd/hub”,
      “register”:true
   },
   “capabilities”:[
      {
         “browserName”:“Android”,
         “version”:“8.1.0”,
         “maxInstances”:1,
         “platform”:“ANDROID”,
         “deviceName”:“emulator-5554-Android”,
         “newCommandTimeout”:30,
         “deviceReadyTimeout”:5
      }
   ]
}
```

Json config 2:

```
{
   "configuration":{
      “proxy”:“org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy”,
      “cleanUpCycle”:2000,
      “port”:53173,
      “host”:“127.0.0.1”,
      “maxSession”:1,
      “hubHost”:“127.0.0.1”,
      “registerCycle”:5000,
      “hubPort”:4444,
      “timeout”:10800,
      “url”:“127.0.0.1:53173/wd/hub”,
      “register”:true
   },
   “capabilities”:[
      {
         “browserName”:“Android”,
         “version”:“9”,
         “maxInstances”:1,
         “platform”:“ANDROID”,
         “deviceName”:“ce10182aea56932604-Android”,
         “newCommandTimeout”:30,
         “deviceReadyTimeout”:5
      }
   ]
}
```

Hub is running on port 4444.
Have used appium command line to start two appium server at ports 59793 and 53173.

Comment: i'm getting same issue.

Comment: Hi @T.Che , the issue is resolved now. We need to pass one more capability 'systemPort' in the desired capabilities. Set this capability different for each connected node or devices. The value of this capability ranges from 8200 to 8299.

Comment: thanks for help, my issue was different and i solved it.